# Metro XAML Apps - DependencyProperty.AddOwner

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Im writing some custom controls in Metro XAML, and I noticed the `DependencyProperty` no longer has the `AddOwner` method. Does anyone know if there is a new way of doing this in Metro ?

Answer (score 2):

Add owner API has been removed from Silverlight and metro XAML as well. There is no equivalent API for this any more.

You should be able to yield similar ability by defining a new dependency property, and data binding them. But I know it cannot fully replace add owner. If you post your underlying motivation for add owner, we might be able to help.